# Is Splitting WPF Application into multiple dll's is good or bad?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, exe

Previously my WPF Application size was 4096KB as a single .exe file.

Now i have splitted the application as multiple like this

```
JIMS.exe           Main Application-->103KB
JIMSDAL.dll        Data Access Layer-->43KB
JIMS.Core.dll      Core classes for MVVM-->110KB
JIMS.Commands.dll  MVVM Commands-->11KB
JIMS.Controls.dll  WPF UserControls-->25KB
JIMS.Resources.dll Fonts,icons and xaml resources.-->44KB
UtilityClasses.dll Other classes like Helper classes-->10KB
```

I am further thinking to add two more dll by removing the viewmodels from JIMS.exe into JIMS.ViewModel.dll.

Now my question is, Is this a good way to spit Single EXE into multiple dlls,

Please let me know what are the advantages and disadvantages of this.

I have some opinion like, if there are more dlls, JIMS.exe will struggle to contact many dlls using the application. Since for each call it has to read respective dlls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the single .exe?

Comment: i thought, when a exe of size 4096KB is loaded, i will consume lot space than loading a exe of 103KB, and then it will load only the need dll for it.

Comment: Your exe uses a lot dll already(from .NET framework). Is it struggle?

Comment: Ya dynamic linking is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen it mentioned, so I'll chip in.

In my experience, the main reason to use this approach in C# is `exchangeability` - to easily be able to replace parts of the system.

To give an example, we use this approach in my current project. Each GUI component (or `UserControl`) is its own dll, and is dynamically imported at launch. This allows us to implement a plugin-architecture for our GUI as well as allowing our GUI Developers to work in separate projects and not have to load all the logic/etc.

I can't tell you if it's "good" or "bad" - it's what you need for your specific purpose. What I can tell you is that it's not *"wrong"*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use those dlls independently in other projects then sure you may split them, otherwise what is the benefit ? I am not sure about your application but if you are writing a control, to be used by other developers or an application to be integrated in other applications then managing the dlls separately may become a difficult task. I am not too sure about your last opinion. I would like to see the community input towards it

Answer (score 0):

It has many benefits:

-If you are doing a small update, your users doesnt have to download the full exe, they only have to download some dlls, which are alot of smaller
-If you are coding another program, which is using the dll, your users could save memory
-If your program become huge and you have a build time of minutes, you dont have to rebuild all, if you are making changes, you can just build the changed dll again

But it has some negative perspectives:
-Your users could delete dlls(if they are really stupid) and then wonder why the program isnt working anymore
-Without dlls, your users can quickly build a portable version

If your project is huge(it sounds like, because 4MB exe), i would split the programm, but if it is a small programm, I wouldnt split the programm.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed a similar approach in an application I'm developing, but for me the primary reason is to enable development of a console version of the app. That way I can use the XAML GUI to provide easy one-at-a-time operations in the app, and then schedule longer-running/maintenance operations using the console version. They both use the same model and view-model layers, but are obviously different "views".

To me that feels like one of the great benefits of MVVM, especially if you're breaking the components into separate projects/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on a large scale application targeted to a specific niche market but many of our customers require small bespoke applications that, while tailored to their needs, they often use a number of different features of the product which used a single database. Because of this we have our Wpf application split into many different assemblies which is the only real way of being able to do this. In many way it almost make these additional tool which we create part new development and part integrating existing development making these new applications very quick to put together with mostly tested code.

Comment: So... the answer is saying "it's not just good, sometimes/often it's a must"?

Answer (score -1):

It is good to split applications in multiple dll. That makes the project more easy to manage, easier to add/remove features and easier to write a completly new application using the existing dll.
I think dynamic linking is better for the application.....

**Good Things About Dynamic CALLs**

1. You don't need to relink your application if you change something in your subroutine; only the subroutine DLL needs to be relinked.
2. All executables that call this subroutine will share the same DLL; both the code and data.  Since your application only loads one copy of a dynamically called subroutine, it uses less memory.
3. Changes in values contained within the dynamically called subroutine are available to all the DLLs that use it, because they all share the same copy of the subroutine.
4. You can free memory that a dynamically called subroutine was using by CANCELing the subroutine.  This is, however, not generally of much use in the 32-bit Windows virtual-memory environment, since Windows will 'page out' inactive data from the computer's real memory pool anyway.
5. List item

**Bad Things About Dynamic CALLs**

1. Every dynamically called subroutine must be linked as a DLL (unless you use an import library to expose other entry points in a DLL). Therefore, if you application consists of hundreds of subroutines and they're all called dynamically, you will need to distribute hundreds of DLLs.
2. It's possible to mix versions of your DLLs.  This can be a problem both with distributing your application and with end-users installing updates improperly.
3. If one of your DLLs is missing, you may not know about it until the user exercises some facility that tries to call that DLL.  At that point, your application will terminate abnormally unless you handle this situation.
4. If you CALL a DLL, CANCEL it, then CALL it again, you incur more I/O because the routine needs to be reloaded if you CANCEL it.  This can slow down an application because it requires more disk activity.  Again, in the Windows environment this is usually unnecessary because Windows does an excellent job of managing memory.
5. If you mix and match static and dynamic calls to the same subroutine, your software might have several different versions in memory at once.  Guess how much fun it will be trying to debug THAT mess?

For more info see [Here](http://www.screenio.com/tips/calls.htm)

Comment: Is there even a linker with .NET assemblies?

Comment: Almost every bullet item does not apply.